# Avoid new line when writing to console character by character

Tags: c#

I'm trying to use the writing text effect on an app.  I got it to work, but my problem is that the code writes one letter on each line and moves downward instead of left to right.  How can I correct this?
Here is the code block:

```
Console.Clear();
string text1 = ("You spot a rabbit. What will you do?\nA Leave it \nB Eat it!");
for (int i = 0; i < text1.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(text1 [i]);
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(75);
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: You're using `WriteLine`, it adds a line break at the end of every character you passed to it, so it just wraps every character into a new line. If you want to animate text (I guess that's what you wanna do) - that's not easily possible with the system Console.

Comment: That worked! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah..  'Console.Write'  works for the way you want..

Comment: Please convert this sentence into proper SO answer. Otherwise it would deserve downvotes due to very low quality.

Answer (score 5):

To clarify this question and for people who look up this question:

> The **Write()** method outputs one or more values to the screen
>   without a new line character.

Different to:

> The **WriteLine()** always appends a new line character to the end of
>   the string. this means any subsequent output will start on a new line.

So you just have to change the code to:

```
    Console.Clear();
    string text1 = ("As you slither forward, you spot a rabbit close by. What will you do?\nA Leave it \nB Eat it!");
    for (int i = 0; i < text1.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.Write(text1 [i]);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(75);
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
```